# DNS Manager for MacOS

Tags: osx, macos, vpn

I'm looking for a DNS Manager for MacOS.

But basically I'm looking for [YogaDNS](https://www.yogadns.com/) alternative for MacOS.

Here is the major (and really the only) functionality that I need:

> DNS server management
>
> - Assign specific DNS servers for specific DNS names using flexible rules
> - Use a specific network interface, such as a  VPN connection, for a specific DNS name (e.g., *.corp.example.net)

So I want to be able to manage rules for DNS requests and assign various DNS servers based on some predefined rules.
The end goal is to be able to assign specific DNS servers to specific VPN connections.

Right now I'm having real troubles setting up a VPN client to connect to this one company VPN server on mac, because they are using some old implementation of openvpn that is I suspect is  not configured properly and for some reason openvpn client for mac can not negotiate to use their DNS server after connecting to VPN server.

I have solved this problem on Windows using YogaDNS, applying the rule "If you see a connection to *.this-company.com, use this DNS server", so I want to do the same on Mac.